# getLine x times haskell

Tags: haskell, io, stream

Based on [Hackerrank question](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/find-digits)

My problem is how can I do getLine t times on stdIn?

```
main = do
    t <- getInt
    let x = [divisorsInNumber unsafeGetInt | a <-[1..t] ]
    print x

getInt :: IO Int
getInt = fmap read getLine

unsafeGetInt :: Int
unsafeGetInt = unsafePerformIO getInt

divisorsInNumber n = length $ filter (== True) $ map (isDivisor n) (integralToListOfInts n)
```

Comment: [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?q=Int+-%3E+m+a+-%3E+m+%5Ba%5D)

Comment: Also, there is `readLn`, which behaves like `fmap read getLine` but with better handling of unreadable things.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just replicate t times the `getLine` operation with `replicateM`:

```
import Control.Monad (replicateM)

getLines :: Int -> IO [String]
getLines t = replicateM t getLine
```

Thus `getInts`, that is `getInt` t times, can be expressed with:

```
getInts :: Int -> IO [Int]
getInts = fmap read <$> getLines
```

The full code rewritten to use `getInts` could be:

```
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))
import Control.Monad (replicateM)


getLines :: Int -> IO [String]
getLines n = replicateM n getLine

getInts :: Int -> IO [Int]
getInts n = fmap read <$> getLines n

getInt :: IO Int
getInt = fmap read getLine

divisorsInNumber :: Int -> Int
divisorsInNumber n = length $ filter (isDivisor n) (integralToListOfInts n)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    t <- getInt
    nums <- getInts t
    let x = [divisorsInNumber num | num <- nums]
    print x
```

Comment: Or `getInts = getLines >>= return . fmap read` if you don't want to import `<$>` from `Control.Applicative`

Comment: Yes, you can write it like that.

Comment: @Rufflewind: `<$>` is IMO quite standard enough to ratify using it anywhere it works well. I'd definitely prefer it over ``f `fmap` x``.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I agree with you but it's subjective. Any of the proposed solution is ok.

Comment: `main = fmap (map divisorsInNumber) (getInt >>= getInts) >>= print`

Comment: @AndrewC indeed, I was trying to not change too much the original example.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: I like the aesthetics of `<$>` better but when I want to make code that's easily copy-pastable I use `fmap` for convenience's sake.

Comment: Thanks for all different versions in different syntax